# Extract x previous key-value pairs given a key from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
 dict_test ={1: 111, 2: 2222, 3:333, 4:4444, 5:5555, 6:6666,
        7: 777, 8: 8888, 9:9999, 10:100010101}
```

and would like to create a subset of the dictionary, that takes the previous four values given the key 8 for instance. So the resulting expected dictionary would look like this:

```
 dict_new ={4:4444, 5:5555, 6:6666, 7: 777, 8: 8888}
```

I tried to write a more general function below, where I can more generally determine how many previous values I should look back.

```
def get_x_prev_entries(dictionary: dict, key: str, prev: int):
   if key in dictionary:
      token = object()
      keys = [token]*(prev*-1) + sorted(dictionary) + [token]*diff
      print('keys' + str(keys))
      new_dict = []
      newkeys = []
      new_prev= prev
      # extract all keys that are between 0 and the specified difference
      while new_prev is not 0:
          new_prev -= 1
          if len(newkeys) == 0:
              newkeys= newkeys
          else:
              newkeys = newkeys.append(keys[keys.index(key)-new_diff])
              print(newkeys)
          print(new_diff)

      new_dict = {k:v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k in newkeys}
      return new_dict
  else:
      print('Key not found')
```

So to create my desired dictionary I would ideally enter

```
get_x_prev_entries(dict_test, 8, 4)
```

but at this moment I only get an empty dictionary returned. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an order dict

```
from collections import OrderedDict as od

dict_test ={1: 111, 2: 2222, 3:333, 4:4444, 5:5555, 6:6666, 7: 777, 8: 8888, 9:9999, 10:100010101}

od_dict = od(dict_test)

def get_previous_keys(od_dict, prev=4, given=8):
    if given not in od_dict:
        return
    k, v = [], []
    for i in range(given-prev, given):
        k.append(i)
        v.append(od_dict[i])
    return dict(zip(k,v))

print(get_previous_keys(od_dict))

{4: 4444, 5: 5555, 6: 6666, 7: 777}
```